# Finding range of $\frac{x^2}{x^2 -4} $

Tags: calculus, functions

Find range of $$\frac{x^2}{x^2 -4} $$

Finding domain of this ,I can do it . But what about the range ? I do not know how to handle the numerator .. thanks

Comment: Rewrite it as $1 - \frac {4}{x^2-4}$. Now you just need to know the range of $x^2-4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}$. Since $f(0)=0$, $0$ belongs to the range. Besides,$$\lim_{x\to2^-} f(x)=-\infty$$and therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, $(-\infty,0]\subset\operatorname{range}(f)$.

On the other hand$$\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1.$$Therefore, $(1,+\infty)\subset\operatorname{range}(f)$.

And what if $\lambda\in(0,1]$? Well, you have\begin{align}f(x)=\lambda&\iff\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}=\lambda\\&\iff x^2=-4\frac\lambda{1-\lambda}<0,\end{align}which has no solutions.

So, $\operatorname{range}(f)=\mathbb{R}\setminus(0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \frac{x^2}{x^2 -4} $$

$$ x^2 = \frac{4y}{y-1}$$

$\implies y>1$ or $y\le 0$ as $x^2>0$

So, range = $(-\infty, 0] \cup (1,\infty) $

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)= 1+\dfrac{4}{x^2-4}$, $x$ real.

Consider: $g(y) = 1+ \dfrac{4}{y-4}$,

$y\ge 0,$  $y \not=4.$

1) $0 \le y \lt 4:$

Range$_1$: $(-\infty,0]$

2) $y \gt 4:$

Range$_2$: $(1,\infty )$

Altogether: $(-\infty, 0]\cup(1,\infty )$